# Modify part of legend's colour in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have plotted with the following code:

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(data = mpg, aes(x = displ, y = cty))+
  geom_point(aes(size = hwy, color = cyl, shape = drv))+
  guides(colour = guide_colourbar(order = 1),
         alpha = guide_legend(order = 2),
         size = guide_legend(order = 3))
```

Now I want to change the legend's colour from `black` to `grey` (as shown in the image below), how could I do that? Thanks.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do:

```r
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(data = mpg, aes(x = displ, y = cty))+
  geom_point(aes(size = hwy, color = cyl, shape = drv))+
  guides(colour = guide_colourbar(order = 1),
         alpha = guide_legend(order = 2),
         size = guide_legend(order = 3, override.aes = list(color = "gray")))
```

[image]